# Search a line and replace line

Tags: search, replace

```
false###File.txt 
many rows
###online = false --> ONE SHOT import (delete all table contents before importing)
###online = true  --> DIFFERENTIAL import (import without clean the table contents)
###online = true

many rows
```

I want to select lines having online alone and replace true with false but it need not be row number 3 it can come anywhere in the file

My attempt  : test.sh

```
online=true
perl -i -p -e "s/^(online[ ]*=[ ]*).*$/\1 $online/" File.txt
```

It does the work but adds a space before false. Can someone correct above command so that it doesnt add a space before the word true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `sed`:

```
sed -i '3s/true/false/' file.txt
```

If you want to keep the original file as `file.txt.bak`:

```
sed -i.bak '3s/true/false/' file.txt
```

Also if you want to replace more than one occurrence of `true` with `false` in the same line:

```
sed -i.bak '3s/true/false/g' file.txt
```

**EDIT:** As per your clarified query, Try this:

```
sed -i.bak '/DIFFERENTIAL\|[^t][^r][^u][^e]$/!s/true/false/' file.txt
```

This will replace "true" with "false" in the lines where there is no "DIFFERENTIAL" and also where "true" comes at the end of the line.

Comment: The problem with this it It need not be row number 3 it can come anywhere in the file

Comment: @Peck: Please update your question and add this info..also how to know the string of which row to replace and which row to keep..

Comment: @Peck: You can replace value from any row, just use the row number instead of `3`..if its the 100th row: `sed -i '100s/true/false/' file.txt`

Comment: the thing is I dont know where it will come in the file          think this might work testing this    ### sed '/DIFFERENTIAL/!s/true/false/g'

Comment: @Peck: so how to know the row number then?

Comment: i was looking for pattern search like if last word in a line is true and if it doesnt have DIFFERENTIAL in the line then change true to false

Comment: ---> Your clarified answer works well but i want to do the change from true to false only on lines that has online not all lines

Comment: Heemayl  this command doesnt seem to work                                                                  sed -i.bak '/DIFFERENTIAL\|/ONE SHOT/!s/online*/online = true/' file.txt

Comment: @Peck i am on a tour right now..replying to you via the mobile app..i would get back to you whenever i get a chance..if you want help right now please ask a new question using different title & example..

Answer (score 0):

I found following command that will help me:

```
sed '/DIFFERENTIAL/!s/true/false/g'
```

Comment: Check the edit in my answer..there is a problem in your current pattern, it does not match if "true" is at the end of the line..